# Stream JSON output in Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, java-stream

My application is built using Spring Boot(1.3.3.RELEASE) with Spring MVC, Spring data JPA Hibernate. MySql is the database and Jackson is the JSON serializer. On java 8.

I want to return a huge data set in my controller method. Instead of retrieving all the data and then passing into the Jackson serializer, I want to return a stream of objects like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidates/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Stream<Candidate> getAllCandidates(){
    try { 
        return candidateDao.findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
    } catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error("Exception in getCandidates",e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

my DAO is like below:

```
@Query("select c from Candidate c")
public Stream<Candidate> findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
```

However, Jackson is serializing the stream object instead of the contents of the stream. The actual output below:

```
{"parallel" : false}
```

How can I instruct Jackson to serialize the content and not the stream object?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to [this](https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/spring-streams-memory-efficiency) I was able to solve the issue.

I had provide a custom httpMessageConverter that understands how to handle streams. Like so:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper =jsonConverter.getObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Stream");
    module.addSerializer(Stream.class, 
        new JsonSerializer<Stream>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(Stream value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                 serializers.findValueSerializer(Iterator.class, null)
                .serialize(value.iterator(), gen, serializers);
            }
    });
 
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity: how do you read that `Stream<Candidate>` using `RestTemplate`?

Comment: Stream.iterator is a terminal operation. meaning that it cache everything in ram. this is no difference to use Iterable as the getAllCandidates output

Comment: Currently looking into reducing memory footprint for large datasets and spring mvc just like in this post. How do you mean it caches everything in memory? Is this pointless?

Answer (score 4):

## Return `Iterable<Candidate>` from your controller

Stream converts to an iterator by `Iterable<X> iterable = stream::iterator;`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidates/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Candidate> getAllCandidates(){
    ...

        return candidateDao.findAllByCustomQueryAndStream()::iterator;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposed solution at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/3 which may be the better way to go.

I'll not paste the code in here, as it may get updated in that issue.

So far, I've not found any issues with that proposed code which I've added in with other modules such as the Jdk8Module for Optional as

```
jacksonObjectMapper.registerModule(new StreamModule());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this way of adding support for streams broke the nice output of LocalDate / LocalDateTime, ended up doing it like this:

```
@Bean
public Module customModule() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Stream");
    module.addSerializer(Stream.class, new JsonSerializer<Stream>() {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Stream value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            serializers.findValueSerializer(Iterator.class, null)
                    .serialize(value.iterator(), gen, serializers);

        }
    });
    return module;
}
```