# Streaming REST API

Tags: rest, spring-boot

We are currently using **SpringBoot** to implement REST services where the response is sent in the form of JSON. I am exploring the ways to "**stream**" the response.
Could somebody please suggest different ways/approaches to stream the response.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: I think your question has already been answered, see below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155557/stream-json-output-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream JSON output in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155557/stream-json-output-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet to stream data from a rest endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/streams", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public StreamingResponseBody getStreamingResponse () {

        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    out.write((Integer.toString(i) + " - ")
                            .getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```