# Spring boot stream large JSON dataset

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jackson, java-stream

I have a table that contains 1400000 rows, a controller that returns all of these records JSON format and AngularJS front-end which iterate through these records and then output a pdf file.

As expected calling this controller results in high cpu usage and results in slow or even inaccessible GUI. While searching for a possible workarounds I came across following *[Stream JSON output in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155557/stream-json-output-in-spring-mvc)* about using `Stream`. However, I am unable to make it work, what i did is:

Declare following method in `Repository` interface:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM subscriber", nativeQuery = true)
public Stream<Subscriber> findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
```

Then, calling this method from `Controller` like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/subscriber/all", "/api/subscriber/all" })
public Stream<Subscriber> getAll() {        
    return subscriberRepo.findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
}
```

And a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` like this:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonConverter.getObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Stream");
    module.addSerializer(Stream.class, new JsonSerializer<Stream>() {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Stream value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        serializers.findValueSerializer(Iterator.class, null).serialize(value.iterator(), gen, serializers);

        }
    });

    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

However, when I call `/subscriber/all`, I get following exception:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.

If I annotate `Stream<Subscriber> getAll()` method with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` I get following exception:

> 2017-08-29 23:12:08,022 [][http-nio-8089-exec-10] WARN - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
>
> 2017-08-29 23:12:08,023 [][http-nio-8089-exec-10]ERROR - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>
> 2017-08-29 23:12:08,029 [][http-nio-8089-exec-10] WARN - org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not advance using next(); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not advance using next()

I tried searching but still without any luck, any help on direction in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: `AngularJS front-end which iterate through these records and then output a pdf file` why angularjs is creating PDF, cant this be done at server side and return to client for download?

Comment: What part of the extremely detailed and clear message in the exception don't you understand?

Comment: Spring Controllers can't return and Stream (Is not suported yet. It will be available in Spring 5). Your best option is create the pdf in the backend and steam it direct in the OutputStream.

Comment: No matter even if you manage to stream those records successfully, the browser will die generating a PDF from that much data. Generate the pdf on the server.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, I'm wondering if during the conversion when jackson try to access the `Subscriber` fields it triggers the lazy loading. Also have you tried to experiment with `@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))` ? I think that in this case it needs a specific hint that depends on the database (see http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html)

Comment: I also think that the hibernate session get closed as soon as you enter the mvc domain as pointed here https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/spring-streams-memory-efficiency might be worth to give a try with `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor `

Comment: @waqas did you manage to solve it.