# return response from SpringBoot method in several pieces

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Right now I have a method that works properly in SpringBoot. It receives a POST argument, does some processing on it, and returns a string result (without using a template).

Incidentally I'm not totally sure if I've setup the method signature properly, but as I said it does work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ResponseBody
String processFile(@RequestParam("myinput") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    // do some processing
    String myresponse = 'yadayada';
    return myresponse;
}
```

I'm going to start processing larger files, and as a result I want to return the string `myresponse` in several pieces. So for the string `part1 part2 part3` I might return `part1` to the client immediately, then 10 seconds later return `part2`, then 15 seconds after that return `part3`.

However this won't work without some changes, since right now there's just a single monolithic `return` statement. What do you think is the best way to do this? I've seen some Q&A about "returning a stream" but being new to Java and Spring Boot I'm not sure if there's a distinction between "returning a stream object" and "having the actual response be streaming i.e. in multiple parts"

Comment: I would use a websocket, open it in your client when upload the file, and from the controller when you decide, send notifications to the socket. Also integrate sockets with spring boot its quite fast and easy

Comment: I am not sure what a websocket gets me. I don't really need notifications per se, I just need the response to be "streaming"

Comment: I read a solution using Java 8 Streams (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155557/stream-json-output-in-spring-mvc), but unfortunately I need to use Java 7 for this project.

Comment: I'm going to second the opinion of using [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).  This seems like the perfect solution for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually really simple. Just get a PrintWriter directly on the response, and use it to write and flush data as it becomes available. I don't think this will allow me to take advantage of templates, but otherwise it works.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ResponseBody
String processFile(@RequestParam("myinput") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter =  response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("a");
    printWriter.flush();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
    printWriter.println("b");
    printWriter.flush();
}
```

Comment: You probably want to look into StreamingResponseBody https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-mvc-streamingresponsebody.html